# sparkR : sparkException on createDataFrame

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

I'm trying to run the sample dataframe example using RStudio.
I have the following code:

```
Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME = "C:\\Users\\himanshu.babbar\\Desktop\\Babbar\\Softwares\\spark-1.6.0-bin")
Sys.setenv('SPARKR_SUBMIT_ARGS'='"--packages" "com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.2.0" "sparkr-shell"')

.libPaths(c(file.path(Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), "R", "lib"), .libPaths()))

library(SparkR)

sc <- sparkR.init(master = "local", sparkHome = SPARK_HOME, sparkEnvir = list(spark.driver.memory="512m"))
sqlContext <- sparkRSQL.init(sc)

# Create a simple local data.frame
localDF <- data.frame(name=c("John", "Smith", "Sarah"), age=c(19, 23, 18))

# Convert local data frame to a SparkR DataFrame
df <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, localDF)
```

On doing this, I'm getting the following exception :

```
Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1012)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:482)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:455)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:715)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.chmod(FileUtil.java:873)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.chmod(FileUtil.java:853)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.fetchFile(Utils.scala:406)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies$5.apply(Executor.scala:404)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies$5.apply(Executor.scala:396)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:772)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:98)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:98)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:226)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:39)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:98)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:771)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies(Executor.scala:396)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:192)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I'm able to run a similar code on my colleagues machine so this could be a configuration thing that i may have been missing. Any pointers here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to have a `Hadoop` version and/or libraries mismatch.  This may not be *"simple"* to fix.

Get someone who understands Hadoop installations to take a look at your setup and then ensure the version of `Spark` you are using supports the Hadoop version on your machine (or the cluster you are connecting to).

Comment: Essentially, the Hadoop_home property was missing from the environment and I corrected it with the following code : Sys.setenv(HADOOP_HOME = "C:\\Softwares\\hadoop-2.6.0") but you did point me in the right direction so Thanks

Comment: @hbabbar Glad you were able to diagnose and fix it.